# How to assert that two arrays are disjoint?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, chai, assertions

I'm using chai to write unit tests and I would like to assert that two arrays are disjoint (i.e. they do not share any common element).

Something like this:

```
assert.areDisjoint([1, 2, 3], [2, 4]);    // fail

assert.areDisjoint([0], [1, 1, 2]);       // pass

assert.areDisjoint(['foo'], ['foo']);     // fail

assert.areDisjoint(['foo', 'foo'], []);   // pass
```

I had a look at the many various predefined assertion [here](http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/) and [here](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/), but nothing seems to fit.

My current (working) approach:

```
assert.equal(
    new Set([...array1, ...array2]).size,
    new Set(array1).size + new Set(array2).size,
    'expected iterables to be disjoint'
);
```

I think you can see why I don't like this method: it makes the intent unclear and bloats the code. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to write this assertion.

Comment: `const isDisjoint=a1=>a2=>a1.filter(v=>a2.includes(v)).length===0`
But this is not efficient.

Comment: array2.forEach(e => expect(array1).to.not.include(e))

Answer (score 1):

A fallback possibility is to create a helper function/method as part of the test code.  Then, the tests would look like:

```
assert.isTrue(areDisjoint([1, 2, 3], [2, 4]));  // fail
```

Within the test code the intent is clear, the implementation of the 'areDisjoint' function is at one place and does not cause any code bloat.  Unfortunately, in case of a failing test the diagnostic message is not overly helpful, but can only tell something like 'expected true got false' or the like.